# How setState() can get 'state' without this in React class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I am a student who started studying React. While studying about class components, I have a question. I have a question from this.setState inside the click() function of the source code below.
'this.setState' can get a state which is parameter in arrow function. How can 'setState' just get the previous state? I wonder how it is possible to get it with just state, not this.state.
I guess it is related to the inherited React.Component class, but I would appreciate it if you could give me an accurate answer.

```js
class Component extends React.Component {
        state = {
          count: 0,
        };

        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.click = this.click.bind(this);
        }

        click() {
          this.setState((state) => ({ state, ...{ count: state.count + 1 } }));
          console.log(this.state);
        }

        render() {
          return (
            <div>
              <button onClick={this.click}>click!</button>
              {this.state.count}
              {this.props.message}
            </div>
          );
        }
      }

      ReactDOM.render(<Component message='기본값 아니지롱' />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

Comment: `state` is the name you have given for the argument that react passes to the function you give to `setState()`. It doesn't need to be called `state`, you could have called it anything, eg: `foo => {...foo, counter: foo.count + 1}`. It's the same concept for all callbacks, such as `event` in `.addEventListener("click", event => {});`

Comment: I think my question is wrong. I wonder how setState knows prevState is correct question. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `this.state` since state is a property of your class and not a standalone variable.

`setState` can access state since you declare that variable at the start of your arrow function. you could also call it banana. the first parameter of the arrow function gets filled with `this.state`.

Answer (score 0):

The `state` inside the `callback` function of `this.setState` is already the previous state, which is more accurate than `this.state`.

You could rename the parameter inside the callback whatever you want:

```js
this.setState((prev)=>{ prev, ...{ count: prev.count + 1 } }); // This works even better, since the prev here does not equal to this.state and more accurate
```

For details you could refer to [this link](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> state *(in the function above)* is a reference to the component state at the time the change is being applied. It should not be directly mutated. Instead, changes should be represented by building a new object based on the input from state and props.

Comment: thanks to your reply. But I wonder The state inside the callback function is already previous state.